# Is there any reason against using red onion, or a mixture of red and yellow onions to make an onion soup?

Tags: soup, onions

Should I use yellow onions, red onions or even a mixture of both to make the best onion soup?

I realise this is a subjective question, but is there any reason I shouldn't use red onions or is there an advantage to using a combination of onions?

Comment: I habitually make onion soup using a mixture of red onion, white onion, leeks(!) and shallots and personally think it tastes fantastic, so I don't see why not =)

Comment: So I should just throw in all onions and all onion-related vegetables in to the pot? I like it.

Comment: Take a look at this related question about red onion in soup: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22124/8305

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would simply use whatever onions I had available! Red onions have a milder flavour than yellow onions (therefore red is usually preferred in salads) and obviously different colour but the difference is still small enough to interchange with no problem. Unless, of course, you desire a particular colour in the soup or are particular about the soup having a strong or mild flavour. Leek would make it even milder and sweeter. If I'd have to make a choice I would use yellow onions and spare the red ones for raw/decorative use.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a reason not to use both other than preference. I make a delicious 5 onion soup that uses both red and yellow along with a few others of course. I know you didn't ask but to ensure it doesn't just taste like onion water I caramelizs my onions for the soup as well.