# Can I make French onion soup with red onions instead of white?

Tags: soup, onions

All the white onions have been used for something else, all I have is the red onions, I would cook the red onions the same way, according to the directions, correct?

Comment: Yes, but I think it will taste different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did my French onion soup with 'red' onions come out tasteless and bland?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/22124/why-did-my-french-onion-soup-with-red-onions-come-out-tasteless-and-bland)

Comment: @DebbieM. : this might not be a duplicate if someone has a solution on how to make a good onion soup w/ red onions.

Comment: How sweet do you want the soup to be?

Answer (score 4):

While I've never seen it done, a quick review of several popular French Onion Soup Recipes either do not specify the type of onion or [specifically allow for it](http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/french_onion_soup/).
So the answer to your question would be 'yes you can'. The food police will not come busting through your door for making "French Onion Soup" with red onions.

Now, the next question is "Will anybody like the results?"

You should probably start with a simple substitution of the red onions and follow the same recipe. (The linked recipe doesn't distinguish between red or yellow onions in amounts or process)